# Probability Test

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

There are three mutually exclusive events in a test program. The outcome of the program can either be A, B or C. The probability of the events are calculated as: A=0,4865 B=0,4865 and C=0,027.

After running 10 Test simulation the out come had been:

1.A

2.B

3.B

4.C

5.B

6.B

7.A

8.B

9.A

10.A

How can I now calculate the probability of the 11th test to be A again and take into account the 10 test simulations.

Comment: What makes you think your "A=0,4865 B=0,4865 and C=0,027" does not apply to future simulations including the $11$th?

Comment: I am trying to derive a formula which takes old test simulations into account, to estimate the probability of the next outcome.

Comment: Your $10$ observations have $4$ As, $5$ Bs and $1$ C. Do you think that this might increase or decrease your probability for A from $0.4865$? Why?

Comment: I think if I run the 11th simulation the probability of A, B or C must adjust, depending on the past results, so that after the outcome the eleven simulation fulfill that A=0,4865 B=0,4865 and C=0,027.

Comment: If the outcomes are independent, then $P(T_{11} = A) = 0.4865$. If they are not independent, you need to specify their dependency relation

Comment: You would need a sample size of a multiple of $2000$ to have $0.4865$ as a possible exact observed proportion; even then you would not be sure of seeing this unless you had some kind of sampling without replacement in full from a population of that size.  You might want to read about the [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy)